# CLion is automatically printing back input from standard input, is there any fix for this?

Tags: c++, cmake, mingw, clion

I am trying out CLion to write some basic C++ programs but every time I feed in some input using `std::cin` or `std::getline` the input is printed back to the console for no reason.

For example if I run this program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){
    string name;
    std::cin >> name;
    std::cout << name << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and type thomas and press enter I get this output

```
thomas
thomas
thomas
```

when instead I should get just

```
thomas
thomas
```

I am using CLion/Mingw64 on Windows 10 x64

Comment: You enter `thomas` and press enter.  That means at least one will be displayed.  Do you see one more or two more(for a total of three)?

Comment: Yeah sorry, edited the question, my fault, basically I see the thomas that I wrote, the one that gets printed by cout but I can't understand where is the third one coming from

Comment: Okay.  Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: I build your program and ran it and I do not see a third instance of Thomas.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your code.

What you observe is a side effect of using WinPTY under the hood. By default, CLion uses it to communicate with a debugged program on Windows.

Here's the corresponding bug in our issue tracker: [CPP-2580 User input appears twice in output window in CLion under MinGW](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-2580), please feel free to upvote the ticket.

While there's no proper fix for the issue yet, you may use a workaround suggested in comments to that ticket to disable PTY:

> Open Registry via Find Action, type `run.processes.with.pty` and disable this pty setting.

Comment: This issue is still valid and is running on OSX too.