# Clion `cout` and `cin` combination causes console to not work properly

Tags: c++, io, c++17, clion

I've recently started trying out CLion for C++ programming. I wanted to test a sample application (below):

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Please enter a number: ";
    int x;
    std::cin >> x;

    std::cout << "Your number was " << x << "!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

This is what I was expecting (the number is user input):

```
Please enter a number: 10
Your number was 10!
```

And this is exactly what happens when I compile and run manually (`g++ main.cpp -o main && ./main`)
However, this is what happens when I run with CLion:

[image: input and output not working properly]

Does anyone know why this is happening, and how I can fix this?

**Note:** I am using CLion with the g++ compiler (version `9.3.0`) on WSL2

Comment: Why *what* is happening? That all looks fine.

Comment: @NicolBolas First of all, the space after the "Please enter a number:" text is not printed. Secondly, after passing input in, it's printed back out on the next line, even though my code never says to do that. Everything after that is fine; just the combination of `std::cout` and `std::cin` seems not to be working correctly.

Comment: @NicolBolas I should probably point out that this works as expected when I just run `g++ main.cpp -o main` and then `./main` instead of clicking the "Run" button in CLion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more searching, I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46731077) StackOverflow post, which led me to [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-2580) issue (upvote it!) which finally led me to do what was told in the comments:

> Two workarounds are available:
>
> - Turn off PTY: by disabling run.processes.with.pty option in the Registry (Help -> Find Action -> Registry...)
> - Use Cygwin64 instead

I did the first option and CLion works fine now:

[image: CLion working]

It looks like this is an issue with MinGW and WSL.

Answer (score 0):

I have met the same issue in CLion.To solve this problem, I sent an email to the specialist on the CLion support team.And here is their answer:

> Generally, stdin and stdout are not synchronized unless they're run in
> an interactive terminal environment. You can emulate this by enabling
> the Emulate terminal in the output console option in the Edit
> Configurations tab

[image][image]